# How to create a java.sql.Blob object in Java SE 1.5.0 with a byte[] input?

Tags: java, jdbc, blob

I want to create a Blob object from a byte[] input to update a table using `PreparedStatement#setBlob()`. In J2SE 6, we have [`java.sql.Connection#createBlob()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createBlob%28%29) to get this done. Is there anything similar to this available in J2SE 1.5.0? What is the best way to update a BLOB type column with a `byte[]` data in J2SE 1.5.0?

Comment: The answer to your question is very much related to what jdbc driver you are using, and what database you are using.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An example, using [SerialBlob](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html):

```
import java.sql.Blob;
import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob;

byte[] byteArray = .....;
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(byteArray);
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to worry about creating [`Blob`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) objects at all. Treat them as blobs on the database, and `byte[]`s in Java. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some.table")
public class MyEntity
{
    @Id
    int myId;

    @Lob
    byte[] myBlob;

    // snip getters & setters
}
```

If you're really intent on creating a `Blob` instance yourself, you can use the [`SerialBlob`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html) implementation:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
Blob myBlob = new SerialBlob(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to actually create the Blob itself. When doing a prepared statement, use a ByteArrayInputStream for the parameter when setting the blob parameter.