# org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

This line of code:

```
document.setContent((Blob) file);
```

Is throwing this error:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
```

Where `file` is a `MultipartFile`.

Eclipse does not throw any warning message from the "offending" line of code above.  In fact, eclipse added the `(Blob)` cast itself as part of a suggested fix.

Is there some other way that I can quickly and easily convert a `MultipartFile` to a `Blob`?

I have been working on this problem for a number of days now to no avail.  See postings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586865/hibernate-error-sqlexceptionhelper-unknown-column-documents1-file-in-field) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577782/using-jpa-entity-manager-to-import-blob-into-mysql-in-spring-application).  Simply being able to convert the `MultipartFile` to a `Blob` in a line or two of code would be an easy, elegant solution to an otherwise overcomplicated problem.

Comment: @MichałRybak At the moment, I am testing with PDF files. Does it make a difference?

Comment: probably not, but I was curious if `setContent` has any overloaded versions, e.g. `setContent(byte[])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278894/how-to-create-a-java-sql-blob-object-in-java-se-1-5-0-with-a-byte-input).
What I've come up with is to use `byte[]`:

```
byte[] contents = file.getBytes();
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(contents);
document.setContent(blob);
```

Comment: Thank you. +1 for trying to help. System.out.println(document.getContent().length()); Shows the blob has a length when called after being set by your code.  But the application is not inserting the blob into the database. I guess technically you answered my question, so I will mark this as answered, but will you please look at the other two postings I linked to in my original posting above?  If you could help me get this working, I would be very grateful, and mark all three as answered when the application successfully inserts a document into the database.

Comment: I put a large bounty on a related question.  Do you mind taking a look at it and submitting an answer?  I will award the large bounty to the person who provides a working solution.  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586865/document-not-saving-in-spring-jpa-document-manager-application

Comment: sorry but I'm not that much into Hibernate at the moment. I've read your other questions, but I'm afraid I can't help. I can only suggest using debugger to see precisely in which step the data is lost. Also consider enabling Hibernate logging to see what SQL it executes, if you haven't done this already.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I am a self-taught programmer, and I do not know how to do the things you are suggesting.  Are you willing to post links to instructions?

Comment: Read [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/) about enabling Hibernate showing SQL. As for the debugger, it depends on your version of Eclipse, but you can just google it and find some articles like [this one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html). Good luck!